# Do any USB-C hubs include 4-10 USB-C ports with same capabilities as original port?

Tags: usb, thunderbolt, hub

It's simple to find a multi-port USB 3.0 hub, where one USB-3 port becomes 4-10 equivalent ports, like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00E6GX4BG). Does this kind of product exist with 100% USB-C ports? That is, when connected to a single USB-C port on my computer, the hub should provide 4-10 **USB-C** ports that provide *exactly the same capabilities* as the original port on my computer.

By "exactly the same capabilities," I mean that my computer's ports work with monitors and AC power adapters, so the ports on the hub should also work with monitors and AC power adapters.

It's easy to find USB-C hubs that provide HDMI, USB-3, Ethernet, a single charging port, etc., but I've never seen a hub like I describe above. If none exists, is there a technological reason why? (Or is it just due to sales/marketing?)

Comment: "works with monitors" uses something called "alternate mode", which means it uses a different kind of transport, which won't work in an USB-3 hub because (unlike the computer itself) it has no way to provide the source of the transport (graphics card output) for each of the ports, and the alternate modes can't be multiplexed in the same way as USB-3. Charging capabilities are a complex subject, but in principle a hub should be able to charge in the same way as the original port, given a power supply for the hub.

Answer (score 2):

Shortly: NO.

Long: it gets really complicated, for sure there are bandwidth limitations and a hub will always be limited.

If you also introduce external display support, you should be aware that this cuts the maximum possible bandwith a LOT.

You will probably never be able to use a 5K external display and have a 10GBe ethernet connection from a single USB-3.0 hub.

Powering over USB-C limits also the maximum speed, so in that aspect USB-C is kinda doomed because it only introduced a standard port but when it comes to capabilities, there are lots and lots of footnotes to read.... as in "you get A feature only when B AND C XOR D happens.